# Parse Data From WebView into my fragment android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I want to parse json data using web view into my fragment to identify my web page login status. 
My Containing Data:
{"loginID":0}

Here 0 means I am currently not logged in my web page using web view, 
1 means I am logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some web services? You can use JavaScript interfaces for WebView to jump from JS code into Android code and then send response to the specified Fragment.

Take a look here: [addJavascriptInteface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)).

Send some source code or describe more what has to be done.